# Selenium ChromeDriver maximum wait time

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I am setting default max wait to 4 mins as below

```
Driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(240));
```

But occasionally during a particular test I want a shorter or longer span so we do this

```
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
    Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout);
```

Where timeout is the wait time in seconds, however the default still appears to remain at 240, is this correct or am I doing something silly?

Thanks in advance